# Uncaught TypeError:Undefined is not a function Box.js: 9

Tags: typescript, react-redux, material-ui, box

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>  Box.js:9
> Box.js:9:21
>  Box.js:9`

I am getting this error and nothing is being rendered in my browser.
Here is the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Tried deleting `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` and re-installing them, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example to your question.

Comment: We can't address issues in code we can't see, so please do [edit] your post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, the complete error message and any accompanying error stacktrace, and any debugging or investigation details you have already collected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.